# Downloading and save a file and keeping the same file name

Tags: xcode, swift, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to download an .mp3 file thats exists on my webserver, using `NSURLConnection` delegates.
My questions is how to keep the same file name with its extension (.mp3) in the `DocumentDirectory` without renaming it?

Here is what I did in `connectionDidFinishLoading` but its not complete.

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("AudioFiles")

    self.songData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering, What is the audio file name saved as by default and is it in a folder of some sort?

Comment: @Jesster2k10 lets say the file i'm downloading is 'abc.mp3' which is located is the webserver. I want it to be saved as 'abc.mp3' in the 'Document' folder.

Comment: You can get the connection.currentRequest.URL.lastPathComponent!

Comment: You're using iOS, right?  Because if you were using Mac OS, it would be easier to use `NSURLDownload` instead of `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0] as String

    let description = connection.description()
    var descriptionArr = split(description){$0 == "/"}
    let descriptionArrCount = countElements(description)
    if descriptionArrCount == 0
    {
         return
    }
    let fileName = description[descriptionArrCount - 1] as String        

    let filePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    self.songData.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

}
```